# R remove \\n in sentence

Tags: r, string

I want to remove \n in a sentence using R. However, I am unable to remove it. Nothing happen to my sentence. My sentence is UTF-8 encoded, which I get the sentence from read.csv() .

```
sentence <- "To be there with a samsung phone\\n"

str_replace_all(sentence , "[\r\n]" , "")
# [1] To be there with a samsung phone\\n

gsub("\r?\n|\r", "", sentence)
# [1] "To be there with a samsung phone\\n"

gsub("[\r\n]", "", sentence)
# [1] "To be there with a samsung phone\\n"

str_squish(sentence)
# [1] "To be there with a samsung phone\\n"
```

Nothing happen - the \n is not removed. How can I remove it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Each backslash must be escaped (doubled): `gsub("\\\\n", "", sentence)`.

Comment: thank you, this is what I want to solve! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `\\n` inside an R string literal is *not* a newline, it is a literal backslash followed by the character `n`.  You wanted to use this version:

```r
sentence <- "To be there with a samsung phone\nHello World"
sentence
[1] "To be there with a samsung phone\nHello World"

gsub("\r?\n", "", sentence)
[1] "To be there with a samsung phoneHello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the back slash as it is itself an escape character. Try `stringr::str_replace(sentence, “\\n”, “ “)`. You might need to add a few more backslashes if there are more.